# Does Ghidra expose any local code to remote servers?

Tags: ghidra

I wanted to experiment with the graphing capabilities of reverse engineering tools to attempt to debug a complex memory corruption issue.  Specifically trying to discover the possible sources of corrupt register values in highly optimised code, where doing the analysis by hand has been incredibly tedious and time consuming.

I was considering using IDA Free but having to ship the binary is against policy.  Ghidra appears to be the second most popular tool, but I am having trouble confirming it doesn't have any similar remote components.

Does Ghidra keep everything local if you built it yourself off of github, or is there any potential for it also to leak the binary to a remote party?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a definitive answer online, but seeing as Ghidra is open-source, I would assume that they don't capture any telemetry. It would most likely be a major point of criticism and many folks would be hesitant to use it otherwise. You can always prevent the executable from communicating over the internet if you want to be extra safe.